# Signal emit Issue - Listview is not showing full list

Tags: c++, listview, qml

I am binding a ListView with values passed from the cpp.

Issue: Listview displays only one row, mean first value, The rest of the rows are not appeared.

Checked:
I created an ListModel/ListElement in main.qml as test and bind with ListView, Now the Listview just working fine, display all values

I suspect after the signal emit, the error occurs.

Code snippet:

main.qml

```
ListView {
    id: idListView
    anchors {
        left: parent.left
        leftMargin: 10 * scaleFactor
        right: parent.right
        rightMargin: 10 * scaleFactor
        top: rectangleToolBar.bottom
        topMargin: 10 * scaleFactor
        bottom: rectangleStatusBar.top
        bottomMargin: 10 * scaleFactor
    }
    // model: objHomeController.detailsModel // Display only one row
    //model: idListmodel //Working fine
    delegate: comsearchDelegate
    spacing: 10 * scaleFactor
    clip: true

    highlight: Rectangle {
        color: 'grey'
        Text {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            color: 'white'
        }
    }
    focus: true
}


Component {
    id: comsearchDelegate
    Row {
        spacing: 10 * scaleFactor

        Column {
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignTop

            Text { text: title; font { pixelSize: 14 * scaleFactor; bold: true } }
            Text { text: description; font { pixelSize: 14 * scaleFactor; bold: true } }

        }
    }
}

ListModel {
    id: idListModel
    ListElement{
        title : "sdfsdf";
        description:"sdfsdfs";

    }
    ListElement {
        title : "sdfsdf";
        description:"sdfsdfs";
    }
    ListElement {
        title : "sdfsdf";
        description:"sdfsdfs";
    }
    ListElement {
        title : "sdfsdf";
        description:"sdfsdfs";
    }
}
```

HomeController.h

```
Q_PROPERTY(Model* detailsModel READ get_detailsModel WRITE set_detailsModel NOTIFY detailsModelChanged )
```

HomeController.cpp

```
void HomeController::set_detailsModel(Model* value)
{
    m_detailsModel = value;

    //value has correct values - checked.
    emit detailsModelChanged(value);
}

Model* HomeController::get_detailsModel(void)
{
    return m_detailsModel;
}

void HomeController::getAllData()
{
    m_detailsModel->clear();
    m_detailsModel->updateModel(eveReadXML());
    set_detailsModel(m_detailsModel);
}
```

Model.cpp

```
void Model::updateModel(const QList<Details> & details)
{
    if(this->rowCount() > 0) {
        this->clear();
    }

    beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(),rowCount(),rowCount());
    m_modelData.append(details);
    endInsertRows();
}
```

Since I came from .Net background, I would like to understand binding a Listview/GridView to a DataTable or an XML. Here I followed, Created class called Details [Details.h] and created Model.h/Model.cpp and fetching the value from there and binding to ListView. Am I doing right, Or do we have other flow. Any tutorial/Codesnippet/Link for projects highly appreciated.

Comment: How did you arrive at the conclusion that is has anything to do with the signal?
As far as I can tell from your description it is working fine, otherwise the view would be totally empty.
My guess would be that your model is not working correctly. Have you actually tested it?

Comment: Could you show us defination of `get_detailsModel()` ?

Comment: Dear Ansh, I posted code above as a flow.

Comment: It's hard to find where is the problem due to brief code. Working code stripped to the minimum will be helpful. Please post a working code.

Answer (score 0):

To define ListModel from c++, you need to subclass  QAbstractListModel

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractlistmodel.html

You can take example on QQmlObjectListModel in this project : http://gitlab.unique-conception.org/qt-qml-tricks/qt-qml-models

Or clone it and use it in your project as follow :

```
Q_PROPERTY(QQmlObjectListModel<Details>* detailsModel READ get_detailsModel WRITE set_detailsModel NOTIFY detailsModelChanged)
```